# Nginx Angular App can't access REST API on localhost in production

Tags: nginx, node.js

I've searched around quite a bit and still haven't found a solution that works for my issue...

We have a NodeJS application that is an Express app exposing a REST API on localhost:3000. We also have an AngularJS application that is built (ng build --prod) and then served by Nginx. On a local machine, everything works fine. When I put it in to production, the Angular app can't access any of the API endpoints.

[XHR Headers Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd2zg.png)

[Developer Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3Gwk.png)

Initially, I thought this could be a CORS problem, so I adjusted my Nginx configuration to be as follows:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;


        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
        }
}
```

That didn't solve the problem. There is no information in any of the Nginx logs, and I can successfully access the REST API via curl when logged in to the server. I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your frontend code should be sending API calls to your backend, wherever it is located, not to localhost.

Comment: The backend is not exposed on the internet, but relative to the frontend, it is available at localhost. Are you saying that the solution is to put the backend on the internet and have the frontend hit a public URL for the backend?

Comment: You have code running in _the user's browser_! That code must be able to reach your server. But it's trying to reach localhost instead. Localhost is always the local host, never a remote host. That's what it means.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, and I'm looking for a solution wherein the frontend code can access an API that is not exposed on the public internet.

Comment: I don't think you have any choice other than to use the Internet, at least not until IP can be transmitted by magic.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Angular can't resolve localhost, but using 127.0.0.1 works just fine.